# Tinymce Page Landscape Settings

Tags: tinymce

I am not sure if this is possible but is there a way that I can set TinyMce to go Landscape?

I have gone thru most of their tutorials and plugings but cannot find anything

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "landscape" in HTML so you won't find a setting in TinyMCE for something like that.

You can certainly use CSS to manipulate the HTML document inside the editor to visually look wider than it is long but in reality there is no "bottom" to an HTML document so the whole concept really does not make sense.